Как в grid задать для блока максимальную высоту, равную двум блокам сбоку?

Есть три блока в grid контейнере. Я хочу, чтобы блок под номером 3 имел максимальную высоту размером с блоки 1 и 2. У него при переполнении будет прокрутка содержимого. Как это сделать?

Можно использовать расположение по линиям сетки.


.g {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 2fr 1fr;
  grid-gap: 1rem;
  width: 90vmin; height: 90vmin;
  margin: auto;
}

.g > div {
  font: 10vh/2.5 monospace;
  text-align: center;
  border: 2px solid #000;
  border-radius: 0.5rem;
}

.g > .c3 {
  grid-column: 2;
  grid-row: 1 / 3;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

.content { height: 900vh; }
<div class="g">
  <div class="c1">1</div>
  <div class="c2">2</div>
  <div class="c3">
    <div class="content">3</div>
  </div>
</div>




По видимому, я не совсем ясно выразился. Вы задали для grid контейнера фиксированную высоту. Я же хочу, чтобы высота grid зависела от блоков 1 и 2.

Высота блоков 1 и 2 заранее неизвестна

Флексом можно


.container
{
 display:flex;
 height: 500px;
 flex-direction: row;
 align-items: stretch;
}

.block1, .block2
{
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 5px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: stretch;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
}
.block1 div
{
  width:100%;
  height: 50%;
  border: 2px solid #000;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.block1 div:nth-child(1)
{
 margin-bottom:8px;
}

.block2 div
{
  height: 100%;
  border: 2px solid #000;
  border-radius: 5px;
 }
<div class="container">
  <div class="block1">
    <div>1</div>
    <div>2</div>
   </div>
  <div class="block2"><div>3</div></div>
</div>




Через grid-template-areas, + ограничить height вертикального блока и добавить скролл


.container {  
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 200px 250px;
  grid-template-rows: 200px 200px;
  gap: 2px 5px;
  grid-auto-flow: row;
  grid-template-areas:
    "g1 g3"
    "g2 g3";
}

.g1 {
  grid-area: g1; 
}

.g2 { 
  grid-area: g2; 
}

.g3 { 
  grid-area: g3;
}
.g1, .g2, .g3 {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
.g3 {
  max-height: 400px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
<div class="container">
  <div class="g1">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</div>
  <div class="g2">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</div>
  <div class="g3">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</div>
</div>




Я хочу, чтобы высота grid контейнера зависела от блоков 1 и 2, высота которых заранее неизвестна
